# About On-shell subtraction and renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, self-energy

I really want your help, i have tried to solve it for two days but I couldn’t, therefore if you could help me by giving guidance and hint, i really appreciate it.
My question is that how to perform the following derivative from Ref. 1:

$\delta_2 = - \left.\dfrac{d}{d\not p}\sum_{2}(\not p)\right|_{\not p = m_P} \tag{18.43}$

For these two integrals:
$\sum_{2}(\not p) = \dfrac{\alpha}{2\pi}\displaystyle{\int_0^1dx(x\not p - 2m_P)\ln\dfrac{x\Lambda^2}{(1-x)(m^2_P - p^2x)+xm_\gamma^2}}~~~~~~~~~(\textrm{PV})\tag{18.47}$

and
$\sum_{2}(\not p) = \dfrac{\alpha}{2\pi}\displaystyle{\int_0^1dx(x\not p - 2m_P)\left(\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}+\ln\dfrac{\tilde\mu^2}{(1-x)(m^2_P - p^2x)+xm_\gamma^2}\right)}~~~~~~~~~(\textrm{DR})\tag{18.50}$

References:

1. Mathew D. Schwartz, "Quantum field theory and the standard model"; subsection 18.3.1.

Comment: Page 332-333 eq 18.42- 18.47, then i have get eq18.48 and 18.49 , also 18.51-18-52

Comment: What do you want to derive? $\delta_2$?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov i want to derive δ_2 and δ_m for Dimensional reduction and Pauli-Villars regularization of electron self energy and

Comment: For self-energy you should compute the 1-loop 4D integral and here Feynman parametrization is useful. To make integral convergent, you can use dim-reg ($d\rightarrow d-2\epsilon$) or Pauli-Vill reg. Make Feynman parametrization first, perform Wick rotation ($t\rightarrow it$), compute integral over angles, regularize integral over loop momentum. Find the answer. If you want to obtain the answer, you should be more clear and show your own efforts

Comment: The full derivation is easy to find, for instance in https://porthos.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/Public/textos/one-loop.pdf you can find detailed discussion

Comment: Thanks dear @ArtemAlexandrov i have done those steps, what remais is taking the derivatives of those integrals and i have no idea at all about it, i go little steps then i stuck, and for that pdf i couldn’t find similar example of that integral, unfortunately

Comment: Eq. (2.79), (2.81)-(2.83) in pdf mentioned above

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov but there were not such labeled equation in the pdf.

Comment: Oh, sorry, wrong link. Here is correct: https://studfile.net/preview/1812208/ (it is 2004'th version, with explicit derivations)

Comment: Thank you so much @ArtemAlexandrov it was really discussed very compactly I couldn’t get it, thanks again dear.